# Centering a Shape using VBA in PowerPoint 2003

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am programatically copying tables and graphs from Excel to PowerPoint.

Ideally, I'd like to center the graphs on the slide and resize them to fit the slide if necessary.

This shouldn't be too hard, and I can check & modify `.Top`, `.Left`, `.Width`, `.Height` of the shape just fine, but how do I find out the width/height of the slide itself to do the proper positioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you the Height and Width ...

Just divide by 2 :D

```
Sub a()
   Dim a As Presentation
   Set a = ActivePresentation
   MsgBox a.PageSetup.SlideHeight, a.PageSetup.SlideWidth
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: Ok! Say we have a single table in a slide, how to do center it in the slide? Thank you in advance.